# javascript if class is hidden then scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

scroll to the item only if  the class is hidden or when the form opens up. check out the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdE2v/93/
Can you take a quick look? This was the closest I could get to.

```
// toggle and hide all but the form u want to edit
$('[class^="toggle-new-form"]').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).parent().next();
    $('[class^="new-form"]').not(el).addClass('hidden');
    el.toggleClass("hidden");
});

// scroll down to view to see all payment Options
$('.scroll-payment-options').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-payment-options").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: In the case of your JSFiddle, I don't believe you can scroll the window if there isn't enough content to warrant a scrollbar.

Comment: You right. Let me see if i can add it

Comment: Please add all relevant code as an [mcve] to the question itself, not to a third-party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasClass` to check if the element has the hidden class, like so:

```
// toggle and hide all but the form u want to edit
$('[class^="toggle-new-form"]').click(function() {
  var el = $(this).parent().next();
  $('[class^="new-form"]').not(el).addClass('hidden');
  el.toggleClass("hidden");
});

// scroll down to view to see all payment Options
$('.scroll-payment-options').click(function() {
  if(!($(this).parent().find('[class^="new-form"]').hasClass('hidden'))){
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".scroll-payment-options").offset().top
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdE2v/94/)

Comment: @HollyJohnson: [this should work better](http://jsfiddle.net/jdE2v/99/)

Comment: @ amdouglas Your a god

Comment: @HollyJohnson happy to help.